# images does not display in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Images does not display in firefox and in chrome. Safari works fine. I code the image as a background image in CSS and coded the image in HTML. When I preview the page, the image can only be seen in safari. Why? This occurred when I bought a new computer.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="img/background.png" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: show what you have tried so far in code

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the image was not showing in firefox and chrome. The image itself was getting errors. I found out when I tried importing the image into photoshop, photoshopped has an error message saying "Could not place “background.png” because the file-format module cannot parse the file." So I made a new image in the html, and the image displayed on the browsers.